# Want to Update the existing listView in fragment by clicking menuitems

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I am creating an app for finding nearby blood donors. In this app I am using three fragments for swipe navigation. Inn one fragment, the available donor list is shown, but I want to change the list from a menu list by on a clicking particular blood group The 1st list is but when I click the items it shows nothing.

Java code:

```
public class DonorsFragment extends Fragment {

    SwipeMenuListView listView;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    TextView fullName,bloodGroup,gender,age,address;
    Query query;
    View rootView;

    FirebaseListOptions<DonorAdapterClass> options;


    public DonorsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_donors, container, false);

        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);


Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"oncreateview",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         query =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

         setQuery(query);



        SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {

                // create "delete" item
                SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(getActivity());
                // set item background
                deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                        0x3F, 0x25)));
                // set item width
                deleteItem.setWidth(170);
                // set a icon
                deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_phone);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
            }
        };

        listView.setMenuCreator(creator);

        listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        // open

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.blood_group_menu,menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.a_pos: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"A+",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_A_Pos").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.a_neg: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"A-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_A_Neg").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }


            case R.id.b_pos: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"B+",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_B_Pos").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.b_neg: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"B-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_B_Neg").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.ab_pos: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"AB+",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_A_Pos").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.ab_neg: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"AB-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.o_pos: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"O+",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_O_Pos").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.o_neg: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"O-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("canGive_O_Neg").equalTo("yes");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

            case R.id.list_all: {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"All",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                setQuery(query);
                break;
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void setQuery(Query query){

        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<DonorAdapterClass>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.donor_list)
                .setQuery(query,DonorAdapterClass.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {

            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                DonorAdapterClass donors = (DonorAdapterClass) model;

                if(donors.getIsDonor().toString().equals("yes")){

                    fullName = v.findViewById(R.id.fullName_list);
                    bloodGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.bloodGroup_list);
                    gender = v.findViewById(R.id.gender_lis);
                    address = v.findViewById(R.id.address_list);
                    age = v.findViewById(R.id.age_list);



                    fullName.setText(donors.getFullName().toString());
                    bloodGroup.setText(donors.getBloodGroup().toString());
                    gender.setText(donors.getGender().toString());
                    address.setText(donors.getAddress().toString());
                    age.setText(donors.getAge().toString());

                }

            }
        };

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

all firebase query and adapter is set in setQuery() method..when it is called from onCreateView() it is working...but when it is called from switch case in onOptionsItemSelected it shows nothing and previous list view also hides

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Is `onOptionsItemSelected()` being called?

Comment: Yes..i put toast on it

Comment: i forgot to put  adapter.stopListening() in setQuery()

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer in *centuries* so please bear with me. This is not an answer but just pointer to the path towards solution.

Put a break-point at the following points

- onOptionsItemSelected
- case R.id.a_pos
- setQuery()
- setQuery::listView inittialization statement
- setQuery::populateView::donor initialization statement

Run the app. Attach the process with debugger. Now when you click "A+" from options, does it get a response from the server or does it throw an exception?